# `fake-timers` 7.1.x compile error "Cannot find name 'queueMicrotask'."

Tags: node.js, sinon, sfdx

I'm trying to compile a Salesforce sfdx plugin which is a node project with (among others) the following dependency chain that ultimately leads to fake-timers@^7.1.0:

`@salesforce/command@2.2.0` -> `@oclif/test@^1.2.4` -> `fancy-test@^1.4.3` -> `@types/sinon@*` -> `@sinonjs/fake-timers@^7.1.0`.

When compiling it with the Typescript compiler `tsc`, I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@sinonjs/fake-timers/types/fake-timers-src.d.ts:11:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'queueMicrotask'.

11     queueMicrotask: typeof queueMicrotask;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This looks like a bug in `fake-timers-src.d.ts` but introduced in 7.1.0 so I could try to lock the version at 7.0.5 but that might break all kinds of other things.

Does anybody who uses/maintains fake-timers know how to fix this? Or will this be fixed in a future version?

BTW I'm a total NodeJS n00b so if there's something really obvious here that I'm missing, please be kind and just tell me what it is :)

Thanks!
Frans

Answer (score 3):

Frans! fatso83 from the Sinon team here :)

The problem here has all to do with TypeScript and nothing to do with Node, so I feel your pain. No wonder you are wondering. The problem is that the definitions are probably missing that property. For version 7 we tried to generate TypeScript definitions from JSDoc. This works reasonably well for simpler type, but ultimately, TypeScript is more powerful in describing types than JSDoc (like the `typeof` operator), so it was an uphill battle that would never result in the same quality as the types available from [the external Definitely Typed project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sinonjs__fake-timers). We ended up abandoning that effort and therefore this will not be fixed, but it will naturally go away with version 8 (that will not be shipping its own types).

What you can do is this: `npm install @sinonjs/fake-timers@6` (which is the previous version) and `npm install @types/sinonjs__fake-timers@6` (which are the externally maintained types).

You might find some background for this in [this issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/387#issuecomment-858133528).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your workaround this weekend and if it works (around ;) ) I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks for the thorough explanation and I guess fingers crossed that version 8 will be released soon!